# Disable selected tab on button click Mat-Tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-tab

I wanted to disable the selected `mat-tab` and elements inside on a button click,

//HTML

```
 <mat-tab-group #tabGroup>
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let subject of subjects" [label]="subject.name">
        {{ subject.name }}
            <mat-selection-list>
              <mat-list-option *ngFor="let ans of datas">
                 {{ans}}
              </mat-list-option>
            </mat-selection-list>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>

    <button (click)="buttonClick()"></button>
```

//typescript

```
@ViewChild('tabGroup',{static:false}) tabGroup: MatTabGroup;

buttonClick(){
this.tabGroup._tabs[this.tabGroup.selectedIndex].disabled = true;
}
```

Tried using `[disabled]` attribute in ,

But it disabled all the tabs instead of selected one and did not disable the controls.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I am having difficulty visualizing the expected output, suggest adding a snippet. this.tabGroup.selectedIndex.disabled = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.tabGroup._tabs is list of Item you should convert the list into array or you should access the _results property inside Query list

```
this.tabGroup._tabs.toArray()[0].disabled = true;
```

Or

```
this.tabGroup._tab['_results'][0].disabled = true;
```

> [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tab-dynamic-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

You can use default property of `mat-tab isActive`

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab #tab [disabled]='!tab.isActive' *ngFor="let mytab of tabs" [label]="mytab.name">
    {{ mytab.name }}
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Reference : https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api